# Alternative for anonymous namespaces in header-only libraries

Tags: c++

I understand why it doesn't make sense to use anonymous namespaces in header files... They aren't really anonymous...

However, this begs the question:

Is there an alternative idiom/mechanism to avoid polluting the global namespace when distributing a header-only library?

EDIT:

My typical usage of an anonymous namespace is to keep some block of code local to a file so that it doesn't pollute the global namespace. For e.g. if some class had some magic constant, then instead of declaring a global static int, I could declare it in the cpp file:

```
namespace{
    int magic = 5;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same effect without having to use a cpp file?

Comment: "They aren't really anonymous" ? are you confusing "private" with "anonymous"? Those are rather orthogonal concpets in general

Comment: Whats wrong with using a namespace?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you looking for some type of singleton, that is shared across the entire application, or an instance per translation unit? For the latter, an unnamed namespace in a header might be appropriate.

Comment: An a anonymous namespace is for making stuff have internal linkage (in particular, stuff you can't just declare `static`). I don't see what the library being header only has to do with that. Though I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: OT: On the usage of ["begs the question"](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/begs-the-question) :)

Comment: @StoryTeller: I want to achieve an effect similar to internal linkage, but in a header-only file... Essentially writing some code that is not exposed to the rest of the files.

Comment: Well. Each TU will have its own definition of `magic`. They are all different.

Comment: @P.W [Desciptivism vs presciptivism](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2010/02/16/descriptivism-vs-prescriptivism-war-is-over-if-you-want-it/) :)))))

Comment: Sorry that I am not being clear. I do not care about the copy effect. What I care about is hiding a portion code. For instance, I might have several overloads of `foo` and a single `foo_impl` method that is used by all of them. I want to hide the `impl` method so that the user cannot call it.

Comment: Oh. Then like @Luka answered. Do as they do in boost or Python. Assume your clients are responsible adults. Protect them from accidentally shooting their foot off, but not from doing it intentionally (you can't do that anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ doesn't have any mechanism to make entities in header files *completely invisible* to users. They can be made *inaccessible* if you want. This is normally achieved by member access control. You have to make `foo_impl` a private (possibly static) member of some class. Overloads of `foo` would then be either members or friends of the same class.

Alternatively, if you make `foo_impl` a member of a namespace named `detail` or `foo_private` or some such, users will normally understand they *should not* call this function. This works well in practice. Users will still be able to access the function at their own risk, but they will understand the risk. This should be plenty enough, as C++ doesn't protect you from malicious users anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/main_overview/namespaces.html), there is sometimes used namespace named `detail`

> Functions not intended for use by applications are in `boost::math::detail`.

Comment: ...but note that this is just a convention.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe - That works rather well in many great libraries, and languages even. There isn't really a way to prevent a determined enough programmer from doing something they should not.

Comment: Sure; I'm just saying that it's not as strong as (e.g.) private accessibility. It's like a "keep off the grass" sign, rather than a fence.